# Is it possible to know if my visitor is logged into facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, status, loginstatus

I want to know if a visitor to my website is logged into facebook or not?
And what information will I be able to fetch from the user's fb profile, so that to login user on my website if user had already synced his fb account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only create an App and check if the User is authorized - without authorization, he is completely anonymous. What information you can fetch is explained in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

For example, you can check if the user is logged in with `FB.getLoginStatus`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook's API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) has a function `FB.getLoginStatus()` that returns either a `connected`, `not_authorized` or `unknown` string depending on if the visitor has authorized your application, has logged in to facebook or neither.

If you want user data, like a picture or a name, you're gonna need to authenticate your application.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure I got it right: If I authenticate my app (the website), I will be able to query user data? Of is the user required to "login" from my page in order to allow me to see the data?